# Signal end of image stream using NetworkStream

Tags: c#

I have a client-server scenario where the client sends images to the server every second. I don't want to close the connection every time I send an image to signal the end of stream. I want to keep the network stream open to reduce overhead of reestablishing a connection. How can I signal the end of an image stream?

I tried using `NetworkStream.Flush()` after sending the image bytes, then sending an ASCII encoded string to signal the end of image, however, according to Microsoft's documentation, `NetworkStream.Flush()` method is not affective "because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no effect on network streams".

How can I solve this problem?

Client:

```
client.Connect(_host, _port);
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    while (_isRunning && client.Connected)
    {
        byte[] buffer = CaptureScreen();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} bytes", buffer.Length);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    while (_isRunning && client.Connected)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                _form.ConsoleWriteLine($"Received {bytesRead} bytes");
                // TODO: If end of image stream break from read loop
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
            _form.UpdateImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the image size before send the image content.

```
stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, 4);
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

At server side stop as soon as received affirmatory bytes.

```
int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
int imageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
     totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
     if(totalBytesRead == imageSize)
     {
         //Save image
     }
     else if(totalBytesRead > imageSize)
     {
         //May happens, split the buffer.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Firstly, you need to work out if the overhead of opening and closing the connection is really that bad, my gut feeling is this would be minimal... if it is totally unacceptable to you, then you really only have 2 reliable options. Send some sort of byte combination that that signals the end. Or send a size before each image, so you are aware of the size and end.

**Original**

[Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **Remarks** This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns
>   the number of bytes successfully read. **If the socket is closed, the
>   Read method returns 0**. The Read operation reads as much data as is
>   available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter.
>   **If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data
>   has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return
>   zero bytes**.

All you need to do is close the client

```
...

if(SomeCondition)
   break;
```

Though, you might also want to catch appropriate exceptions on the server, they can and will happen

Comment: Closing the connection is what I am trying to avoid. I don't want the overhead of reestablishing a connection every second.

Comment: @mr.coffee your question was a little unclear to me, updated